Has there been a clarification regarding whether the use of 'Get Real' move is encouraged or discouraged?
In the Flying Circus book there is a move called Get Real

When you speak the truth from your heart, and they are willing to listen,
choose a goal from below, take 1 Stress, and roll +Calm.
• Restore their Trust in you. They do not take Stress.
• Take them on as a Confidant, or repair a relationship.
• Begin a Move Exchange.
• Remove 3 Stress from the other person.
• Remove 3 Stress from yourself (Net -2 Stress total).
On a hit, you do it. On a 16+, additionally choose one.
• Both of you take 2 XP.
• Both of you lose 1 additional Stress.
• Hold one. Either of you may spend the hold to gain Advantage
while addressing a problem discussed in the conversation.
If you miss, all parties take 1 additional Stress, and the GM asks the
move target, “What did they say which hurt you?”

After the move the author wrote

This move is the ‘act like a grown-up and have a real conversion’ move.
We all agree this is gross and you should do it as infrequently as possible.
But maybe something that happened in the last mission is chewing up
your insides.
Dieter is hurting and needs to talk to somebody. You can’t
stand the rift that’s formed between you and Miriam. You need to finally
tell Anton how you feel about him. That sort of thing.

I am confused as to what the author is trying to encourage here. The "We all agree this is gross and you should do it as infrequently as possible." seems sarcastic but it is hard to tell over text. Has the author made any clarification in further books or through a social media channel regarding whether players are encouraged to have their characters use this move or not?

You should read it sarcastically.
The book starts out with a four-page bumper on content and safety. It's not a work that believes that people shouldn't have grown-up conversations with each other.
However, your player character, let's call him Julian, is (in most cases) a young, thrill-seeking hedonist, which is why he's pursued a career in being borne aloft thousands of feet in the air by a vehicle powered (in most cases) by rapid, repeated explosions. You know -- internal combustion engines.
What's Julian's opinion of a grown-up conversation, do you think?
The reason that a grown-up conversation carries such a significant benefit, and the reason it's a risk to have one, is that for Julian, something like that isn't seasoned, practiced, or routine. But hey, Julian's done a lot of gross things he'd rather not do again in the service of stopping that rapid repeated explosion vehicle from becoming a fireball on the landscape. He'd probably also do one in the service of helping someone trust him again.
